# Infinitely lazy factorial in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, factorial

In a similar fashion as the Fibonacci series may be generated as follows,

```
fibs :: [Integer]
fibs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

how to define the series for factorial.

**Update**

Embarrassingly enough, tried this quite before adding this question,

```
Prelude> let factorial = 2 : 6 : zipWith(*) factorial (tail factorial)
Prelude> take 5 factorial
[2,6,12,72,864]
```

Indeed the numbers in the tail are not successive values, to start with.

Comment: What did you try? SO is not an exercise solving service, but we can prod in the right direction if you show some effort.

Comment: `factorials = <gap> : <gap> : zipWith (*) <gap> (tail factorials)`. Fill in the gaps.

Comment: @chi, entirely agree; note update with unfruitful (embarrassing) attempt quite before formulating this question

Comment: The attempt you did before is just like the Fibonacci series, just with multiplication, the list corresponds to _2^fib(i+1)*3^fib(i)_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lets take a step back and remember where that lazy version actually comes from:

```
fib 0 = 1
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

We can also define the factorial similarly:

```
factorial 0 = 1
factorial n = factorial (n - 1) * n
```

As you can see, our zipping operation is actually `(*)`, and the second list won't be a sublist of `factorials`, but instead `[x..]` with an appropriate `x`:

```
factorials = 1 : zipWith (*) factorials [x..]
```

What value should `x` be? Well, the second element should be `1 = 1 * 1`, so it's `1`, naturally:

```
factorials = 1 : zipWith (*) factorials [1..]
```

Note that we only need to give the first element, since we don't use `tail` or something similar. As you can see, your attempt was almost correct. You just used the wrong values for the left hand side:

```
Prelude> let factorial = 2 : 6 : zipWith (*) [4..] (tail factorial)
Prelude> take 10 $ factorial
[2,6,24,120,720,5040,40320,362880,3628800,39916800]
```

Remark: The factorial sequence is 0!, 1!, 2!, ..., so if you want to be OEIS compliant start with `[1,1,...]`.

Comment: The factorial sequence, as defined in [A000142 of OEIS](http://oeis.org/A000142) starts with `[1, 1, 2, ...]` not `[2, ...]`. Just saying.

Answer (score 7):

The idiomatic definition of a lazy list of factorials is not recursive at all: instead it uses the Prelude function [scanl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:scanl%20scanl).

```
factorials = scanl (*) 1 [1..]
```

Comment: In Haskell 1.2 you could even write `products [1..]` :-)

Answer (score 3):

Given the usual definition of `factorial`:

```
factorial :: Integer -> Integer 
factorial 0 = 1
factorial i = foldr (*) 1 [2..i]
```

we can generate an infinite list of all factorials by simply running the `factorial` function over an infinite list of all positive numbers:

```
inFact :: [Integer]
inFact = map factorial [0..]
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63553ee0163e8c24)

Answer (score 0):

```
factorials = helper [1..]

helper (x:xs) = x : help ([x * (head xs)] ++ (tail xs))
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**